# Nested vs. flattened functions

Tags: solidity, contract-design, transactions

Is there any difference if I use nested functions in a contract instead of writing the code two times if the second function is a subset?

```
function doSmth(address user){
   transaction1;
   transaction2;
}

function doSmthElse(address user){
   transaction2;
}
```

vs.

```
function doSmth(address user){
   transaction1;
   doSmthElse();
}

function doSmthElse(address user){
   transaction2;
}
```

Is it going to take two blocks (double the time) to execute the complete function if it is nested? Is there a difference in gas needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it is not the case that one function call is executed per block rather when the EVM executes a complete transaction it is run until it completes or runs out of gas. If the transaction completes the end state is included in the next block if it runs out of gas you get an out of gas exception. No intermediate state is saved to the blockchain.

Internal function calls are compiled as simple jumps inside the EVM. Thus only difference would be an extra `JUMP` operation for the function call balanced by perhaps shorter code overall.